# Doesn't work move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload one picture to 2 places. It only works first `move_uploaded_file`

```
<?php
    echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['portada_file']['tmp_name'],'img/portada/170x243/zzzzz.jpg').'<br>';
    echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['portada_file']['tmp_name'],'img/portada/170x243/zzzzz.jpg').'<br>';
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
    <input type="file" name="portada_file" id="form_portada_file" value="<?php echo @$_POST['portada_file']; ?>"/>
    <button name="serie" type="submit" class="no_margin_left">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Answer:**

```
1
0
```

Comment: Because the file is moved and no longer exists for the second move. You can copy the file to a new location after it is moved. http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: @Jay Blanchard It's true, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment:

> It's true, thank you so much.
>   You cannot move the file again, because it has already been moved. It no longer exists for the second move.

Once moved you can copy the moved file n to a new location using PHP's [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function, for example:

```
copy('img/portada/170x243/zzzzz.jpg', 'img/static/zzzzz.jpg')
```